# java packages - how to handle repeating names

Tags: java, package

Does it make sense to have "export" organized as below? Not sure if it's common enough or at all recommended practice.

```
org.mycompany.export.generic-export-utilities
org.mycompany.productA.export.productA-specific-export-logic
org.mycompany.productB.export.productB-specific-export-logic
```

Comment: By "organized" do you mean alphabetized? or something else?

Comment: I meant the same name "export" appears higher up and then lower down in the namespacing. Technically it's okay but it doesn't look intuitive from design prospective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good question.

Well, a good way to organize your packages is separate the code by "domain". It's hard to recommend a good package organization without the context of your application. But I will try to help you.

See this example. You have a system that manage Students and Customers. A good way to organize:

```
org.mycompany.student
org.mycompany.student.dto
org.mycompany.student.service
org.mycompany.customer.dto
org.mycompany.customer.service
```

A bad way #1:

```
org.mycompany.dto.student
org.mycompany.dto.customer
org.mycompany.service.student
org.mycompany.service.customer
```

A bad way #2:

```
org.mycompany.student.dto-student
org.mycompany.student.service-student
org.mycompany.customer.dto-customer
org.mycompany.customer.service-customer
```

In this two cases we have some package name repetition.

So, back to your problem, maybe this makes more sense to you:

```
org.mycompany.export.utils //I'm outside of the products subpackages, so this means that this is the place for generics utilities
org.mycompany.productA.export //i'm already in the export inside the productA, this organization already show that the classes inside are specific for productA
org.mycompany.productB.export //i'm already in the export inside the productB, this organization already show that the classes inside are specific for productB
```